# Can I use the same figure twice in a report?

Tags: technical-writing

Is it alright to use the same figure twice (but different figure number) in a report? If so, do I have to use separate captions, to avoid confusion in the table of figures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the figure is central to both problems discussed and quite a bit away in text from both, avoid this.

If the figure is, say, 2-4 pages back (not forward. Introduce it with first reference, then backreference. Don't make forward references) just reference it by name, "Figure X from page Y", don't copy.

If the second occurrence is chapters away but just a mention, with the figure being helpful but not essential, backreference it just the same.

If the FIRST occurrence is just a mention, and the figure is central to the second occurrence, this is where you are allowed to make a forward reference and place the picture by the second occurrence, mentioning it *will* appear and receive more detailed attention further on.

If the occurrences are chapters away, but still the picture is essential to both:

- do copy the picture
- make it perfectly clear this is the same picture as in the earlier occurrence ("Now let us have a look at the graph of ... from chapter X again:")
- skip the repeated occurrence in numbering and the table of figures altogether

Still, it is plain better to have the other figure differ - if only in emphasis. Underline other elements, emphasize descriptions, crop - if it's to illustrate a different thing, it can illustrate it differently, mention the changed emphasis in description, and have the two be two different pictures.